# Laravel get updated request value after merge

Tags: php, laravel, merge, request

I am attempting to modify a Laravel `Request` object using `merge` to update the key `trial_end`.

I am doing this using the following code...

```
if ($this->request->get('trial_end', '')) {
    $this->request->merge(array('trial_end' => 'test'));
}
dd($this->request->all(), $this->request->get('trial_end'));
```

I expect `$this->request->get('trial_end')` to be `test`, but it is not. `$this->request->all()` returns what I expected.

Result of die dump

```
array:1 [
  "trial_end" => "test"
]
"12/4/2018"
```

How come it is not returning the updated value?

Comment: I'd check if in your `$request->all()` there's a field with the value of `"12/4/2018"`. Something might be overwriting your `trial_end` value. I guess you're not showing us all the code.

Comment: @lesssugar This is all the code. The entire `$request->all()` is in the die dump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. The solution was to change

`$this->request->get('trial_end');`

to

`$this->request->input('trial_end');`

This works because `input()` adds the data in `all()` to `getInputSource()->all()` before doing a `data_get` on that, whereas `get()` just performs a `data_get` on the input parameters (pre-modifications).

New code (with a change suggested by Alex)

```
if ($this->request->has('trial_end')) {
    $this->request->merge(['trial_end' => 'test']);
}
dd($this->request->all(), $this->request->input('trial_end'));
```

New results

```
array:1 [
  "trial_end" => "test"
]
"test"
```

Hope this helps any others that come across this issue.

Comment: Also, found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30186169/laravel-request-input-or-get) of interest

Answer (score 1):

the problem it's not with the assignment, but with the comparison, here's my personally best way to check if a value in the request has been set.

```
public function test(Request $request){

    if (!$request->has('trial_end')) { //this is what you have wrong
        $request->merge(array('trial_end' => 'test'));
    }
    return $request->get('trial_end');
}
```

greetings

Comment: This does not work either. I am not trying to add a `trial_end` field, I am simply trying to modify the existing value. `'test'` is place holder.

Comment: I modified your code, and have used the merge function, is this what you want?