# Difference between $request->name and $request->input('name')

Tags: php, laravel

I usually use:

```
$request->name
```

But I know that

```
$request->input('name')
```

is working too. But as it is longer to write I prefer the 1st syntax. But is it always good? Or does it exist some cases where it is better to use the second syntax? Which syntax do you prefer and why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30186169/laravel-request-input-or-get read this also

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method `input()` accept another parameter to set the default in case that attribute is not sent in the request.

```php
$request->input('name', 'Jhon doe')
```

It's very useful especially with checkbox inputs

By default, the second parameter is set to `null`

Also `input()` method supports dot notation to access array data

```php
$name = $request->input('names.0.name').
// instead of 
$names = $request->names;
$name = $names[0];
```