# Laravel Request: Process User Input

Tags: laravel, laravel-request

quick question, about User Input Request to Laravel:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->nameValue;      //Doc: $name = $request->('nameValue');
}
```

Do I have to put all Requests as mentioned in Doc or is the "quick" way also allowed?

There is no difference between $request->value and $request->('value')? Both are working fine so far - but I do not want have any security issues if Im working with $request->value only.

Thanks alot for your help :)

Comment: You mean $request->input('nameValue'). But all methods are fine.

Comment: if you know you want a request "input" I would use `input`, if you use the dynamic property you could get an input or a route parameter

Comment: So there is no difference between $request->value and $request->('value')? Both are working fine so far - but I do not want have any security issues if Im working with $request->value

Answer (score 1):

on laravel, there is a specific class named `Illuminate\Http\Request` which provided an object-oriented way to interact with HTTP request which are send by client-side

- ACCESSING THE REQUEST (both are same speed on accessing data)

```
$name = $request->input('name');
$name = $request->name;
```

- Dependency Injection & Route Parameters

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController; // call the controller

Route::put('/user/{id}', [UserController::class, 'update']); // set a slug as a parameter on routes

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
   return $id; // access the parameter by contoller
}
```

- Retrieving The Request Path

```
$uri = $request->path(); // will fetch the path
```

- Retrieving The Request Method

```
$method = $request->method(); // will fetch the method of request EG: GET / POST / PUT / DESTROY
```

for more information check it on official documentation [LARAVEL](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#introduction)

Comment: So there is no difference between $request->value    and   $request->('value')

Comment: No difference between those two input requests. you can use laravel debug bar for check the progress and performance `https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar`

Comment: Perfect thanks :)

Comment: make sure to ticket the answer

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there will be too many performance issues for different methods to access request's inputs ...
anyway, I will cut an old answer for this question from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30186696/10573560).

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

> get() and input() are methods of different classes. First one is
> method of Symfony HttpFoundation Request, input() is a method of the
> Laravel Request class that is extending Symfony Request class.

so, I think the better one is `input()` method.